# Failed to connect to MFQ:1433 nodejs

Tags: node.js

In my local machine there is no connection issue, but after I pushed to the server and run the node js project it throws an exception:

> Failed to connect to MFQ:1433 - Could not connect (sequence)

- Node js connected to the sql server throw the mssql module
- I have started sql server browser
- In my local machine it working perfectly

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Can anyone help me with this will appreciate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First & foremost please verify that correct PORT is utilized on the connection string (ensure you have one) if you already do then the fix would the below **SQL Server Browser** service is **not running** on the port 1433 on the database server & must be reachable. (Normally the default PORT is 1433)

- Open the SQL Server Configuration Manager.
- In SQL Server Network Configuration select Protocols for [yourServerInstance]. In the right-hand pane, make sure that TCP/IP is Enabled.
- Open the 1433 port in your firewall.
- In the SQL Server Configuration Manager,right-click TCP/IP and select Properties.

  - Select the IP Addresses tab and make sure the TCP Port for IP1 is 1433.  - If you are using a named instance, create an extra rule in your firewall with the port 1434

Comment: default port had to set in connection string . Thanks dude